# Can't get access token for my Venmo acount

Tags: api, token, venmo

I'm trying to write a simple clientside script that used the venmo api to automate some aspects of my account. The first step is getting an access token by going to the developer tab on the settings page. However, whenever I click, "Get Token", the page just redirects me to my profile settings tab with no further information. Going back to the developer tab, nothing has changed, and I still don't have an access token. I've already filled in every aspect of my profile; my name, phone number, profile image, everything. I can't find anyone else with a similar problem. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Venmo API is no longer available to new developers.  I was having the same problem and reached out to them directly to confirm.  The message I received from one of their support staff yesterday:

**Thanks so much for your interest in Venmo! Unfortunately at this time we have discontinued accepting new users of our Developer API. We want to support all of our friends in the development community as much as we can, but at this time we are focusing our efforts towards expanding on our recent launch of the ability to use Venmo to purchase items in select merchant apps. Going forward this will allow us to provide many of the same capabilities previously powered by our Developer API in a more streamlined experience for users and developers alike. I apologize for the inconvenience.**

It's too bad.

Comment: That sucks. I hope they get on that new api soon.

Comment: I think they are going to start getting pulled into the PayPal braintree api